# unable to pluck a column out of a query result in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following query to bring top 5 contributers :

```
$top_cont = DB::table('quests') 
    ->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as contributions'))
    ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->startOfDay()) 
    ->take(5)
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->orderBy('contributions', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

The following is the array output:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#379 ▼
    +"user_id": 2
    +"contributions": 2
  }
  1 => {#380 ▼
    +"user_id": 8
    +"contributions": 1
  }

]
```

I'm trying to use the following to extract only the `user_id`s :

```
$top_ids = $top_cont->pluck('user_id');
```

but having the following error :

> Call to a member function pluck() on a non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have array  then yo can use

```
$array = [...];
$userIds = collect($array)->pluck('user_id');
```